# Stuck on "Connected"

Tags: world-of-warcraft, azerothcore

I have an AzerothCore running on Windows in a local network. After logging in, the client hangs on "Connected" when attempting to enter the realm.

Comment: its great that you answered your own question but I think SO prefers that you should use the answer box below the question rather than put the answer inline within the question. Hopefully it will let you do this with your current rank. And I think you get points even if you answer your own question which is encouraged.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. New to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5):

This is how I've solved the issue:

1. Find and record your Internal IP address. ( It will look like this -> `192.168.xxx.xxx` )
2. Use an MySQL client (e.g. [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/)) to open the database table `acore_auth.realmlist`.
3. Change `address` and `localAddress` from `127.0.0.1` to your internal IP address.
4. Open your WoW client's **realmlist.wtf** file and change 127.0.0.1 to your internal IP address.
5. Log in and enter the realm!